# Making a confirmation dialog box for deletion

Tags: java, android, sqlite, dialog

I've got a simple problem that i can't figure out how to fix.
I have an app that manages contacts, it can Add, update, save, and delete
All i want is to have a confirmation dialog box to appear with a "YES" and a "NO" option when the delete button is clicked.

At the moment i get an error, it doesn't like how I try to access my database to have it delete the contact from the database table.

this is my code:

```
} else if (view == findViewById(R.id.delete)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this contact?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            UserSQL repo = new UserSQL(this);
                            repo.delete(_contact_Id);
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Record Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.close)){
        finish();
        }
```

the line it doesn't like is

```
UserSQL repo = new UserSQL(this);
                            repo.delete(_contact_Id);
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Record Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
```

the problem lies within the `new UserSQL(this)`, it doesn't like how i call my database. This problem only occurs when i try to put it in a dialog method.

My code works perfectly like this when there is no confirmation:

```
else if (view == findViewById(R.id.delete)) {
            UserSQL repo = new UserSQL(this);
            repo.delete(_contact_Id);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Record Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
```

I'd appreciate any help, i researched this problem and couldn't figure out why, i'd love a good explanation and maybe another suggestion to do this in a simpler way if possible at all.

[Error Log](https://gyazo.com/e41987aae683f3d69f088bb0646b81ff)

Comment: try to create another method containing your database codes, and use the method in your positive button.

Comment: post your error log

Comment: I still get the same error, basically the code i use above, if you look at the code inside the onClick method, it doesn't like "(this)" after UserSQL

Comment: Its been solved by the @Shark below, thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lemme try a blind-fix for this:

```
final Activity thisActivity = this;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(thisActivity);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this contact?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        UserSQL repo = new UserSQL(thisActivity);
                        repo.delete(_contact_Id);
                        Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "Contact Record Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: it worked thanks, can u explain to me how it worked though? i see u used a local variable

Comment: the problem was that, `this` outside the AlertDialog points to your activity and it works fine, while in the `AlertDialog::onClick` it points to the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` and thus won't work, because it's not an Activity. The SQL part worked fine, you were getting problems with the Toast, but i used the `thisActivity` in the UserSQL constructor for just-in-case as well.

Answer (score 0):

use: `MainActivity.this` inside `onClick()`

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        UserSQL repo = new UserSQL(MainActivity.this);
                        repo.delete(_contact_Id);
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Record Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :

```
UserSQL repo = new UserSQL(YourActivityName.this);
repo.delete(_contact_Id);
Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this, "Contact Record Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```